# transfer 3D NumPy array into a 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

let's say a NumPy array

```
a = np.array(
    [[[1,2,3],
      [4,5,6]],
     [[7,8,9],
      [10,11,12]]])
```

the shape will be like (2,2,3).
I'd like to make it look like this:

```
a = np.array(
[[1,2,3],
 [7,8,9],
 [4,5,6],
 [10,11,12]]
)
```

which shape will be like (4,3).
if I use reshape, it will look like as:

```
a = np.array(
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9], 
 [10,11,12]]
)
```

Which is NOT what I want. How to do this?

Comment: Swap the 1st and 2nd axis and then reshape: `a.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(-1, 3)`

Comment: Dear @PennYan, If any answer is helpful, consider [upvoting it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401586/13394817). that will be [encouraging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) for answerer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `numpy.stack` and `vstack`:

```
np.vstack(np.stack(a, 1))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more pythonic version of your problem.
This uses concatenate so append the rows of your array.

```py
a = np.array(
    [[[1,2,3],
      [4,5,6]],
     [[7,8,9],
      [10,11,12]]]
)

def transform_2d(a_arr):
    nrow = len(a[:])
    all = a_arr[:,0]
    for i in range(1,nrow):
        all = np.concatenate((all, a_arr[:,i] ))
    return all

print(transform_2d(a))
```

Comment: I tried but I'm afraid reshape can only help with shape but not the result.

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I didn't express it clearly. I edited my question again.

Comment: Noted, I added an easy to read function for your problem. This just combines all your arrays row by row.

Comment: Repeated `concatenate` is not efficient `numpy`  Better to repeatedly append the columns to a list, and do one `concatenate` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

By using indexing method, an `idx` list could be created that specifies which indices of the ex `a` must be placed as which indices in the new one i.e. `idx` is a rearranging list:

```
idx = [0, 2, 1, 3]
a = a.reshape(4, 3)[idx]
```

`a` is firstly reshaped to the intended shape, which is (4,3), and then rearranged by the `idx`. `idx[1] = 2` is showing that value in *index = 2* of the ex `a` will be replaced to *index = 1* in the new `a`.

Answer (score 0):

First use `transpose` (or `swapaxes`) to bring the desire rows together:

```
In [268]: a.transpose(1,0,2)
Out[268]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

then the reshape follows:

```
In [269]: a.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(-1,3)
Out[269]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```